# Why add data to hashtable using different ways in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hashtable, difference

There are two ways you can add data to your Hashtable as shown below:

**First Way**

```
Hashtable ohashtable=new Hashtable();
ohashtable[Key1] = Value1;
ohashtable[Key2] =  Value2;
ohashtable[Key3] = Value3;
```

Or like this:

**Second Way**

```
Hashtable ohashtable=new Hashtable();
ohashtable.Add(Key1, Value1);
ohashtable.Add(Key2, Value2);
ohashtable.Add(Key3, Value3);
```

What is the different's there?

I think this code explain's that.

> First Way can  Add and Update value to same key, because we have used **square brackets**.
>
> Second way is can only Add values to only one key and can't update values  for the same key?

*My thinking is correct? or any other points there?*

Comment: Why are you using non-generic `HashTable` to start with?! It should not be used in any new code. Use generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I know that man, I have just doubt with hashtable.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My Question is `Why add data to hashtable in different ways`? And my thinking are posted in my question. that is correct or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your thinking is correct. Using indexer property *(square brackets)* you can add and update item. Using `Add` item you can only add items. It will throw `ArgumentException` if item with given key already exists in collection.

> *`Hashtable.Item` Property*
>
> Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.

> *`Hashtable.Add` Method*
>
> Adds an element with the specified key and value into the Hashtable.

There is even an exact answer for your question on MSDN:

> However, if the specified key already exists in the `Hashtable`, **setting the `Item` property overwrites the old value**. In contrast, the **`Add` method does not modify existing elements**.

Comment: +1. So this only for reason? or any other reason there?

Comment: @user256103 That's why method is names `Add`, not `AddOrUpdate`. Method name has to reflect it's behavior. I don't know the reason why they behave differently, but otherwise what would be a purpose of `Add` method when you can just use indexer? Despite the fact, that `Add` is required by `ICollection` interface, which `HashTable` implements. Which actually seems to be a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

**directly assign values with the indexer, which uses the square brackets.**

```
   Hashtable ohashtable=new Hashtable();

   ohashtable[Key1] = Value1;

   ohashtable[Key2] =  Value2;

   ohashtable[Key3] = Value3;
```

**call ContainsKey on your Hashtable with the key contents. This method returns true if the key is found, regardless of the value.**

```
Hashtable ohashtable=new Hashtable();

ohashtable.Add(Key1, Value1);

ohashtable.Add(Key2, Value2);

ohashtable.Add(Key3, Value3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way and the second way are different.
 You can use the Item property to add new elements by setting the value of a key that does not exist in the Hashtable.
 For example,  `myCollection["myNonexistentKey"] = myValue`  
However, if the specified key already exists in the Hashtable, setting the Item property overwrites the old value. 
In contrast, the Add method does not modify existing elements.